# SQL: Taking Column From a Row Picked By Aggregate Function in View

Tags: sql-server, sql-view, aggregates

I have three SQL tables: `Release` (which represents a release of a movie), `Media` (which represents the individual pieces of recordable media in those releases; i.e. for Blu-ray/DVD combos, there will be two rows in `Media`, one Blu-ray and one DVD, that point back to the same row in `Release`) and `MediaType` (which defines Blu-ray, DVD, VHS, etc.). There's a one-to-many relationship for `Release`/`Media` and `MediaType`/`Media`, with `Media` being on the "many" side of both relationships. I have a view for `Release`, `vRelease`, which contains aggregate functions, such as a `COUNT` that shows how many media are associated with that release. This is what I have for this view so far:

```
SELECT          dbo.Release.ReleaseID
               ,dbo.Release.Name
               ,CASE WHEN Release.Compilation = 0 THEN 'No' WHEN Release.Compilation = 1 THEN 'Yes' END AS Compilation
               ,dbo.Release.Owner
               ,CASE WHEN Release.LentOut = 0 THEN 'No' WHEN Release.LentOut = 1 THEN 'Yes' END AS LentOut
               ,COUNT(dbo.Media.ReleaseID) AS NumberOfMedia
               ,MIN(dbo.Media.MediaID) AS FirstMediaID
               ,MIN(dbo.MediaType.Name) AS FirstMediaType
FROM            dbo.MediaType INNER JOIN
                dbo.Media ON dbo.MediaType.MediaTypeID = dbo.Media.MediaTypeID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Release ON dbo.Media.ReleaseID = dbo.Release.ReleaseID
GROUP BY        dbo.Release.ReleaseID, dbo.Release.Name, dbo.Release.Compilation, dbo.Release.Owner, dbo.Release.LentOut
```

You'll notice that I've also included two other aggregate columns: `FirstMediaID` grabs the ID of the media associated with that release that appears first in the `Media` table (i.e. if a release has two DVDs associated with it, it gets one with the lower ID value). This column on its own isn't useful; what I want to do is then, in turn, get the `MediaType` that that `Media` is associated with. In other words, I want a column that shows the `MediaType` of the first `Media` that is attached to each `Release`. The column after that, `FirstMediaType`, is supposed to do that, but it instead gets the `MediaType` among all of the `Media` associated with the `Release` and picks the one that is alphabetically first - which means that Blu-ray will always be prioritized over DVD (which is fine), but Audio CD will always be prioritized over everything else (which is not fine).

How do I get the `FirstMediaType` column in this view to get the `MediaType` of the Media identified in `FirstMediaID`?

UPDATE: Here are the tables, their columns and some sample rows.

A couple from `Release`:

```
+-----------+----------------------------------------+-------+-------------+---------+
| ReleaseID |                  Name                  | Owner | Compilation | LentOut |
+-----------+----------------------------------------+-------+-------------+---------+
|         2 | Alice in Wonderland                    | NULL  |           0 |       0 |
|         6 | 4 Film Favorites - Family Comedies     | NULL  |           1 |       0 |
|         8 | Aladdin                                | NULL  |           0 |       0 |
|       463 | Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince | NULL  |           0 |       1 |
|       534 | Spirited Away                          | Ryan  |           0 |       0 |
|       571 | The Original Christmas Classics        | NULL  |           1 |       0 |
+-----------+----------------------------------------+-------+-------------+---------+
```

`Compilation` indicates a release that has more than one movie in it.

Corresponding entries in `Media`:

```
+---------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| MediaID | MediaTypeID |                                        Name                                         | ReleaseID |
+---------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|       2 |           2 | Movie                                                                               |         2 |
|       3 |           1 | Movie                                                                               |         2 |
|      12 |           1 | Space Jam; Looney Tunes: Back in Action                                             |         6 |
|      13 |           1 | Funky Monkey; Osmosis Jones                                                         |         6 |
|      17 |           3 | Movie                                                                               |         8 |
|     620 |           1 | Movie                                                                               |       463 |
|     726 |           1 | Movie                                                                               |       534 |
|     807 |           1 | Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer; Cricket on the Hearth                               |       571 |
|     808 |           1 | Frosty the Snowman; Frosty Returns                                                  |       571 |
|     809 |           1 | Santa Claus is Comin' to Town!; Mr. Magoo's Christmas Carol; The Little Drummer Boy |       571 |
|     810 |           4 | Tracks 1-7                                                                          |       571 |
+---------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

First few in `MediaType`:

```
+-------------+--------------+
| MediaTypeID |     Name     |
+-------------+--------------+
|           1 | DVD Disc     |
|           2 | Blu-ray Disc |
|           3 | VHS          |
|           4 | Audio CD     |
+-------------+--------------+
```

The corresponding entries in `vRelease` SHOULD be this:

```
+-----------+----------------------------------------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
| ReleaseID |                  Name                  | Compilation | Owner | LentOut | NumberOfMedia | FirstMediaID | FirstMediaType |
+-----------+----------------------------------------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
|         2 | Alice in Wonderland                    | No          | NULL  | No      |             2 |            2 | Blu-ray Disc   |
|         6 | 4 Film Favorites - Family Comedies     | Yes         | NULL  | No      |             2 |           12 | DVD Disc       |
|         8 | Aladdin                                | No          | NULL  | No      |             1 |           17 | VHS            |
|       463 | Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince | No          | NULL  | Yes     |             1 |          620 | DVD Disc       |
|       534 | Spirited Away                          | No          | Ryan  | No      |             1 |          726 | DVD Disc       |
|       571 | The Original Christmas Classics        | Yes         | NULL  | No      |             4 |          807 | DVD Disc       |
+-----------+----------------------------------------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
```

But it's actually this:

```
+-----------+----------------------------------------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
| ReleaseID |                  Name                  | Compilation | Owner | LentOut | NumberOfMedia | FirstMediaID | FirstMediaType |
+-----------+----------------------------------------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
|         2 | Alice in Wonderland                    | No          | NULL  | No      |             2 |            2 | Blu-ray Disc   |
|         6 | 4 Film Favorites - Family Comedies     | Yes         | NULL  | No      |             2 |           12 | DVD Disc       |
|         8 | Aladdin                                | No          | NULL  | No      |             1 |           17 | VHS            |
|       463 | Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince | No          | NULL  | Yes     |             1 |          620 | DVD Disc       |
|       534 | Spirited Away                          | No          | Ryan  | No      |             1 |          726 | DVD Disc       |
|       571 | The Original Christmas Classics        | Yes         | NULL  | No      |             4 |          807 | Audio CD       |
+-----------+----------------------------------------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
```

It's that last one that's the problem.

Comment: without `1. sample data` and `2. expected results`, we are just guessing. Please supply a few rows from each table, as formatted text (not images) added into your question. Only then we can do something definite for you. Are there any date columns on any of these tables? (e.g. date of release) Show u the full range of columns available on the tables too.

Comment: Alright, I've added sample rows from each table as well as the actual and desired outputs of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very convenient technique that returns whole rows associated with needs such as "First", "Last", "Earliest", "Latest" is to use `row_number() over()`. Here you want the "first media type", so it is relevant here.

As you will see in the following query joining the [Media] table is replaced with a subquery that includes a row number calculation. Here we `partition by` *ReleaseID* and `order by` *MediaID*, so, for **each** ReleaseID the first row will be the one with the lowest MediaID value. Then in the join to this derived table an extra condition is added to only consider rows with a row number of 1.

**Proposed Query**

```
SELECT
      r.ReleaseID
    , m.MediaID
    , mt.MediaTypeID
    , mt.name MediaName
    , r.Name
    , CASE
            WHEN r.Compilation = 0 THEN 'No'
            WHEN r.Compilation = 1 THEN 'Yes'
      END                        AS compilation
    , r.Owner
    , CASE
            WHEN r.LentOut = 0 THEN 'No'
            WHEN r.LentOut = 1 THEN 'Yes'
      END                        AS lentout
FROM dbo.Release r 
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
               Media.*
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ReleaseID
                                 ORDER BY MediaID) AS rn
        FROM dbo.Media 
        ) m ON  r.ReleaseID = m.ReleaseID and rn = 1
INNER JOIN dbo.MediaType mt ON  m.MediaTypeID = mt.MediaTypeID
```

**Result**

```
| ReleaseID | MediaID | MediaTypeID |  MediaName   |                  Name                  | compilation | Owner  | lentout |
|-----------|---------|-------------|--------------|----------------------------------------|-------------|--------|---------|
|         2 |       2 |           2 | Blu-ray Disc | Alice in Wonderland                    | No          | (null) | No      |
|         6 |      12 |           1 | DVD Disc     | 4 Film Favorites - Family Comedies     | Yes         | (null) | No      |
|         8 |      17 |           3 | VHS          | Aladdin                                | No          | (null) | No      |
|       463 |     620 |           1 | DVD Disc     | Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince | No          | (null) | Yes     |
|       534 |     726 |           1 | DVD Disc     | Spirited Away                          | No          | Ryan   | No      |
|       571 |     807 |           1 | DVD Disc     | The Original Christmas Classics        | Yes         | (null) | No      |
```

[Demo available at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38454/1)

Comment: I figured out another way of doing it, which I just posted, but this did end up working as expected. I'll probably end up sticking with the more... slapdash solution I came up with, since I understand it entirely, but I'll do my best to figure out this one so I can use it again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a simple way to do what I wanted. It isn't as fancy as Used_By_Already's answer (which did end up working, as far as I could tell) and probably breaks a SQL Best Practices rule somewhere, but it's much easier to understand and maintain - at least for my newbie brain.

Since the problem was trying to get the view to use an aggregate column it calculated in a join, I just split the two-step action over two views. `vReleasePre` has all of the columns I outlined in my original query except for `FirstMediaType`. `vRelease` now simply takes all of the columns from `vReleasePre` and adds `FirstMediaType`, which takes its value from a join at the end: `LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vMedia ON dbo.vReleasePre.FirstMediaID = dbo.vMedia.MediaID`, where `vMedia` is a view with all the columns from `Media`, plus the `MediaType` column (I already had `vMedia` lying around).

Since this database is being used in an ASP.NET MVC web application via Entity Framework, and EF has been pretty strange about what it will and won't accept into the data model, I figure that a simple, if roundabout, solution is probably going to be my best option.

`vReleasePre`:

```
SELECT    dbo.Release.ReleaseID
         ,dbo.Release.Name
         ,CASE WHEN Release.Compilation = 0 THEN 'No' WHEN Release.Compilation = 1 THEN 'Yes' END AS Compilation
         ,dbo.Release.Owner
         ,CASE WHEN Release.LentOut = 0 THEN 'No' WHEN Release.LentOut = 1 THEN 'Yes' END AS LentOut
         ,COUNT(dbo.Media.ReleaseID) AS NumberOfMedia
         ,MIN(dbo.Media.MediaID) AS FirstMediaID
FROM      dbo.MediaType INNER JOIN
          dbo.Media ON dbo.MediaType.MediaTypeID = dbo.Media.MediaTypeID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
          dbo.Release ON dbo.Media.ReleaseID = dbo.Release.ReleaseID
GROUP BY  dbo.Release.ReleaseID, dbo.Release.Name, dbo.Release.Compilation, dbo.Release.Owner, dbo.Release.LentOut
```

`vRelease`:

```
SELECT   dbo.vReleasePre.ReleaseID
        ,dbo.vReleasePre.Name
        ,dbo.vReleasePre.Compilation
        ,dbo.vReleasePre.Owner
        ,dbo.vReleasePre.LentOut
        ,dbo.vReleasePre.NumberOfMedia
        ,dbo.vMedia.MediaType
FROM     dbo.vReleasePre LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.vMedia ON dbo.vReleasePre.FirstMediaID = dbo.vMedia.MediaID
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add another join to your `MediaType` table on `FirstMediaId = MediaType.MediaId`

```
;WITH data AS (
    SELECT     dbo.Release.ReleaseID
              ,dbo.Release.Name
              ,CASE WHEN Release.Compilation = 0 THEN 'No' WHEN Release.Compilation = 1 THEN 'Yes' END AS Compilation
              ,dbo.Release.Owner
              ,CASE WHEN Release.LentOut = 0 THEN 'No' WHEN Release.LentOut = 1 THEN 'Yes' END AS LentOut
              ,COUNT(dbo.Media.ReleaseID) AS NumberOfMedia
              ,MIN(dbo.Media.MediaID) AS FirstMediaID
    FROM  dbo.MediaType 
            INNER JOIN dbo.Media 
                ON  dbo.MediaType.MediaTypeID = dbo.Media.MediaTypeID 
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Release 
                ON dbo.Media.ReleaseID = dbo.Release.ReleaseID
    GROUP BY dbo.Release.ReleaseID, dbo.Release.Name, dbo.Release.Compilation, dbo.Release.Owner, dbo.Release.LentOut
)
SELECT data.ReleaseId
      ,data.Name
      ,data.Compilation
      ,data.Owner
      ,data.LentOut
      ,data.NumberOfMedia
      ,data.FirstMediaId
      ,MediaType.Name   as FirstMediaName 
FROM data
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MediaType
            ON  data.FirstMediaId = MediaType.MediaTypeId
```

Comment: I don't think that will work... the `Media` table has a foreign key column called `MediaTypeID` that references the `MediaType` table, not the other way around (so `MediaType.MediaID` doesn't seem to make much sense). Unless I'm missing something. I gave a stab at putting in the join anyways, and it didn't work.

Comment: I tried switching it around so that it was `INNER JOIN dbo.MediaType AS MediaType_1 ON FirstMediaID = dbo.Media.MediaTypeID`, but it just doesn't like me using `FirstMediaID` in a join like that.

Comment: Sorry, I could have clarified, you will need to run the current query into a CTE or Sub-Query and add the join on afterwards, you cannot run a join on an aggregated value.

Comment: What would that look like? I'm pretty new to SQL, and I've never dealt with sub-queries before, much less using them for joins like this.

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example using a Common Table Expression (or CTE)

Answer (score 0):

for the newbie brain, this is the subquery I used

```
    SELECT
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ReleaseID
                             ORDER BY MediaID) AS rn
         , Media.*
    FROM dbo.Media
```

and this is what it does (see the **rn** column)

```
| rn | MediaID | MediaTypeID |                                        Name                                         | ReleaseID |
|----|---------|-------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------|
|  1 |       2 |           2 | Movie                                                                               |         2 |
|  2 |       3 |           1 | Movie                                                                               |         2 |
|  1 |      12 |           1 | Space Jam; Looney Tunes: Back in Action                                             |         6 |
|  2 |      13 |           1 | Funky Monkey; Osmosis Jones                                                         |         6 |
|  1 |      17 |           3 | Movie                                                                               |         8 |
|  1 |     620 |           1 | Movie                                                                               |       463 |
|  1 |     726 |           1 | Movie                                                                               |       534 |
|  1 |     807 |           1 | Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer; Cricket on the Hearth                               |       571 |
|  2 |     808 |           1 | Frosty the Snowman; Frosty Returns                                                  |       571 |
|  3 |     809 |           1 | Santa Claus is Comin' to Town!; Mr. Magoo's Christmas Carol; The Little Drummer Boy |       571 |
|  4 |     810 |           4 | Tracks 1-7                                                                          |       571 |
```

Now keep only those rows with 1 in the **rn** column:

```
| rn | MediaID | MediaTypeID |                         Name                          | ReleaseID |
|----|---------|-------------|-------------------------------------------------------|-----------|
|  1 |       2 |           2 | Movie                                                 |         2 |
|  1 |      12 |           1 | Space Jam; Looney Tunes: Back in Action               |         6 |
|  1 |      17 |           3 | Movie                                                 |         8 |
|  1 |     620 |           1 | Movie                                                 |       463 |
|  1 |     726 |           1 | Movie                                                 |       534 |
|  1 |     807 |           1 | Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer; Cricket on the Hearth |       571 |
```

Then join **just those rows** to Releases and MediaType

### Bingo

= the wanted result.

Not hard, really not hard. You really will want to learn about those window functions because they can solve heaps of problems.

Comment: Hmm... so `rn` increments every time there's an entry with the same ReleaseID, so the first ones will always have an `rn` of 1. Will it still work if they aren't in subsequent rows?

Comment: Yes. If only one row, just get rn=1. If 2 rows, get rn of 1 & 2, and so it goes.  and IF you changed the order direction from ascending to descending, you could get the exact reverse (no that I'm suggesting you want that :) ... but notwithstanding: v.easy & v.handy

Comment: Thanks, that helps me understand the full one you posted in the other answer.

Comment: Right. But you have just leaned a new technique.... if you don't follow what a subquery does, execute it separately. Don't forget I have been offering you sqlfiddle demo sites to play with as well (have you had a look?) So. I accept that perhaps I could have done it earlier, but well, now it's probably a better learning experience for you :)

Comment: I'll play around with it. Thanks for all of your help!